# How to define arralist globally in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

For java class in android we used to declare an int array at top of Activity like `int[] intarray;`
  and the create the object where ever required with 
intArray = new Int(size).

What I do know that in kotlin to use array I need to do something like

```
val numbers: IntArray = intArrayOf(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
```

What I am not able to do is only declare the object globally ie

```
val numbers: IntArray
```

In kotlin we declare variables like `val a: Int = 1` But as shown in basic syntax tutorial it does not let me only declare variable like `val c: Int` and then initialize it when required.It gives me error

> Property must be initialized or abstract

I am getting wrong with the declaration part. As it does not let me define only `val numbers: IntArray`. Can someone tell me where I am getting wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define a not initialized constant variable. Change the following line:

```
val numbers: IntArray
```

by this one:

```
var numbers: IntArray? = null
```

So then, you can modify numbers variable value...

Answer (score 7):

A `val` is a read only value, therefore it has to be initialized immediately, because it's only supposed to be set once. If you can't immediately initialize the array when the `Activity` is created, you should make it a `var`.

This will still have to be initialized: you can, for example, initialize it with an empty array as a default value.

```
var numbers: IntArray = intArrayOf()
```

Or, you can mark it with the `lateinit` keyword to indicate that you don't have anything to assign to it yet, but you know it will be initialized before the first time you use it, and you're taking the responsibility for that:

```
lateinit var numbers: IntArray
```

Finally, you could make it a nullable IntArray, and initialize it with `null`. Here, the compiler will save you from accessing it when it's `null`, but every time you access it, you'll be forced to deal with the fact that it might be `null`.

```
var numbers: IntArray? = null
```

Comment: Oh , need to try that lateinit thing , thank you for the detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

`val` is immutable data variables (read-only). Instead use `var`. For more Info read [defining local variable](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html#defining-local-variables)

So what you need is:

```
var numbers: IntArray? = null // This says numbers variable is nullable
```

and you can initialise it whenever you want.

Comment: That code does not compile, you must initialized the variable

Comment: @AlexTa It was a typo, I changed it.

Comment: you did not initialized the variable yet

Comment: Java affect  :) :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define a not initialized constant variable. Change the following line:

```
val numbers: IntArray
```

by this one:

```
lateinit var numbers: IntArray
```

So then, you can able to initialize whenever you want.